Stereo microphone not recognized as 2 channels on Chrome for Android
I used a stereo microphone and processed the 2-channel sound with Web Audio API. On the Windows PC version of Chrome, I was able to record the sound as 2 channels.(Chrome 127.0.6533.122)
When I used the same code in Chrome for Android on a smartphone, it was only recognized as 1 channel.(Android 10, Chrome 128.0.6613.88)
I am very confused because I want to do the same process as in the Windows PC version of Chrome.
I checked the channelCount in stream.getAudioTracks()[0].getSettings() and it was 1.

I am using enumerateDevices() to select the correct microphone to use.
A stereo-capable recording smartphone app such as “Voice Recorder” correctly recognizes it as 2 channels and can record separate left and right sounds. This is not a malfunction of the microphone or the smartphone.
We have also tried with Android smartphones from other manufacturers, and the same phenomenon occurred.
I also tried Firefox, but the same phenomenon occurred.

My code is shown below:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select name="" id="mic_select"></select>
  <button type="button" id="run_btn">Click</button>
  <p id="res">...</p>

  <script>
    const selectElement = document.getElementById('mic_select');
    
    // Create a list of microphones
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
      .then(function(devices) {
        // extract microphone
        let audioInputDevices = devices.filter(function(device) {
          return device.kind === 'audioinput';
        });
        // Add to dropdown list
        audioInputDevices.forEach(function(device, index) {
          let option = document.createElement('option');
          option.value = device.deviceId;
          option.text = device.label || 'mic ' + (index + 1);
          selectElement.appendChild(option);
        });
      }).catch(function(err) {
        let option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = '';
        option.text  = 'no mic';
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
    });

    // EventListener
    document.getElementById('run_btn').addEventListener('click', async function() {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        // Disable echo canceller to get stereo.
        audio: { 
          'deviceId' : selectElement.value,
          echoCancellation : false, googEchoCancellation: false,
          autoGainControl : false,
          noiseSuppression : false,
          channelCount : 2
        }, 
        video: false
      })
      .then(stream => {
        // Get channel number from audio track
        document.getElementById('res').innerText = 
            'stream.getAudioTracks()[0]\n' + 
            'getSettings().channelCount ' + stream.getAudioTracks()[0].getSettings().channelCount + '\n' +
            'label '      + stream.getAudioTracks()[0].label + '\n' +
            'readyState ' + stream.getAudioTracks()[0].readyState;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        document.getElementById('res').textContent = 'NG';
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

